# PHP preg_match_all() match all words except preposition, adjectives like other less important word in array

Tags: php, regex, artificial-intelligence

PHP preg_match_all() match all words except some word in Array.

```
$input = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.';
$except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');
preg_match_all('/(?<match>\w{3,}+)/', $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches['match']);
```

This give all word with unwanted words.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => Ipsum
    [2] => simply
    [3] => dummy
    [4] => text
    [5] => the
    [6] => printing
    [7] => industry
)
```

Need to return only important words not adjective or preposition adjectives like other less important word in array.

> $except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');

It would be better if we can use one function for this purpose.

Comment: I'd use array_diff to eliminate all the words you have in $except.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a regex with a negative lookahead anchored at the word boundary:

```
'~\b(?!(?:and|the|text|simply)\b)\w{3,}~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfltPQ/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:and|the|text|simply)\b)` - no `and`, `the`, etc. as whole word is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\w{3,}` - 3 or more word chars.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/EcITKn):

```
$input = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.';
$except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');
if (preg_match_all('/\b(?!(?:' . implode('|', $except) . ')\b)\w{3,}/', $input, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => Ipsum
    [2] => dummy
    [3] => printing
    [4] => industry
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to your result and the `$except` array:

```
$input = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.';
$except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');
preg_match_all('/(?<match>\w{3,}+)/', $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r(array_diff($matches['match'], $except));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => Ipsum
    [3] => dummy
    [6] => printing
    [7] => industry
)
```

[demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CJDug)

If you want the result array to be indexed from 0, use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it i.e.

```
print_r(array_values(array_diff($matches['match'], $except)));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => Ipsum
    [2] => dummy
    [3] => printing
    [4] => industry
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to eliminate the words you have in `$except`:

```
$input = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.';
$except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');
preg_match_all('/(?<match>\w{3,}+)/', $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$filtered = array_diff($matches['match'],$except);

var_dump($filtered);

// Output:
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Lorem"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Ipsum"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "dummy"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "printing"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "industry"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `array_diff()` with `explode()`.

```
$input = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing industry.';
$inputArray = explode(' ', $input);
$except = array('and', 'the', 'text', 'simply');
$results = array_values(array_diff($inputArray, $except));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Lorem
    [1] => Ipsum
    [2] => is
    [3] => dummy
    [4] => of
    [5] => printing
    [6] => industry.
)
```